# How to access fields defined in custom annotations in Java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have the following Java code -

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class AnnotationTest
{
    public @interface Size
    {
        int size();
        int location();
    }

    @Size(size = 40, location = 85)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(size = 1, location = 21)
    private String middleInitial;

    @Size(size = 50, location = 115)
    private String lastName;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AnnotationTest t = new AnnotationTest();

        Class<? extends AnnotationTest> classInstance = t.getClass();

        for (Field f : classInstance.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            Size s = f.getAnnotation(Size.class); 
            int size = s.size(); // this is line 29
            int location = s.location();

            System.out.println("size = "+ size);
            System.out.println("location = "+location);
        }

    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.stackoverflowx.AnnotationTest.main(Demo.java:125
```

How to access the annotation fields correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, annotations aren't available at runtime.  You need to add `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` to your annotation definition to make it available for runtime processing.  For example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Size {
```

In practice, you should also check whether or not the field actually has a given annotation with `Field.isAnnotationPresent` before actually trying to get the annotation off of the field.

Also, it's also good practice to specify what types of elements your annotation belongs on with `@Target`.  So your example would then be:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Size {
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. So the issue was reflection.

Comment: Well, I would say the issue was that your annotation didn't exist as far as the JVM was concerned.  That has little to do with reflection per se.